# Errors when using Firebase doc code

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6gjj.png)

```
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this , new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
        FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();

        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failed", task.getException());
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, R.string.auth_failed,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
});
```

(It was brought to my attention that I shouldn't have an image of my code, however I think it makes it easier to see the errors. So both are above)

I'm starting a new firebase project and want to add authentication. I was using the firebase assistant in android studio and copying in the suggested doc code and started getting theses errors when it got to create accounts and signing in. Haven't found any help online. The closest I found was someone who didn't spell AuthResult correctly. Also someone had the wrong tasks library. What am I missing here?

Comment: please, no code in images

Comment: Thanks for the help Tim

Comment: What's in the pop-up window when you roll the cursor over `email`?  "Cannot resolve symbol"?

Comment: No it says,  unkown class: 'email'

Answer (score 0):

The code is misplaced.  It is not part of the body of a method.

Answer (score 0):

put it in  your onCreate(), this should fix it.